# How can I silence the TS2354 error message in TypeScript 2.1.4?

Tags: typescript, webpack-2, ts-loader

I am getting **error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.** on my webpack 2 build using the new `importHelpers` option of TypeScript 2.1.
The bundle seems to build as expected but the error message is troubling.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Or is it a problem with `rxjs\Subject.d.ts` per the error (that mentioned line (Subject.d.ts:9,43) does use and innocent `extends` keyword)?

```
ts-loader: Using typescript@2.1.4 and C:Repro\stuff\tsconfig.json
Hash: f24da06626836e4fc997
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.28
Time: 4256ms
Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
app.js  3.01 kB       0  [emitted]  app
  [1] ./src/main.ts 372 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in C:Repro\stuff\node_modules\rxjs\Subject.d.ts
(9,43): error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.
```

main.ts

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

Observable.timer(3000, 5000)
  .timeInterval()
  .subscribe((interval) => console.log(interval));
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "stuff",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.2",
    "typescript": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "tslib": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'server',
  target: 'node',
  entry: { 'app': './src/main.ts' },
  output: { path: './bin/', publicPath: 'bin/', filename: '[name].js' },
  externals: { rxjs: 'commonjs rxjs' },
  module: { rules: [{ test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }], },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts'] }
};
```

Comment: Shouldn't `tslib` be a dependency, not a devDependency?

Comment: yes indeed.  I just moved it but the problem remains.

Comment: I'm regretting confusing this question with webpack now.  I just tried plain old `tsc` and still get

node_modules/rxjs/Subscriber.d.ts(13,36): error TS2354: This syntax requires an imported helper but module 'tslib' cannot be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is tracked under [this typescript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12724) which should be fixed in TypeScript 2.1.5